# Crossfilter create dimension with data whose have nested objects

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to create graphics with the libraries crossfilter, d3 and dc, and it works well until I create the dimension with an array of objects like this:

```
{ age: 12, name: 'John Doe', ocupation: 'developer' }
```

But when in the data I use nested objects and create dimentions with them it wont works to me.
Nested object example:

```
{ age: 12, name: 'John Doe', nested: { value: 'developer' } }
```

I don't find any docs about how to use crossfilter with nested objects, then is it possible?
How can I do it?

Comment: Preemptively removed vague tags to avoid unwanted (negative) attention. It's usually best to use only the most specific tags when asking on SO. Also the tag is [dc.js] not [dc]; [dc] is an ancient calculator utility for Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the accessor functions for crossfilter, so you can define them however you like.

For example, if you're trying to create an occupation dimension, you could do

```
var occDimension = cf.dimension(function(row) {
    return row.nested.value;
})
```

If this was not your question, you'll need to provide more details and an example of the code which didn't work.